# (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) Can't switch off Airplane mode with physical switch

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, connectivity

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an [MSI GS65 Stealth 8RE](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GS65-Stealth-Thin-8RE#down-manual). When the laptop gets out of sleep mode, air plane mode is on and Linux says it must be deactivated via a physical switch. The FN+F10 combination to turn it off works on Windows, but doesn't on Ubuntu.

When I reboot, everything seems to be fine. So it's not too bad, but systematic and very annoying nonetheless.

I have the usual `rfkill` output :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A review of MSI's manual for your notebook PC shows the manufacturer is Windows-centric, for they provided no drivers, Linux utilities, or physical switch to cycle wireless.

Comment: Tough luck :(
So there's nothing I can try to fix it I guess ?
Because it seems I'm not the only one with this issues on 18.04 in particular.
Anyways, thanks for the input !

Comment: I'm waiting for a bit to see if there's a fix. Otherwise I'll mark as accepted ^^

Answer (score 1):

[There are instructions out there for fixing this on Linux GS65 machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068054/18-04-msi-gs65-wifi-hardware-switch-disabled-after-suspend), but they didn't work for me. My dual-boot GS65 used EFI for boot, while these instructions are meant for GRUB.

Try

```
sudo kernelstub -a "acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=\"Windows 2009\""
```

This won't stop the laptop from entering airplane mode, but the Fn-F10 command will toggle it now (after a reboot).

Comment: yes, but then it will constantly use the discrete video card ... Or is it just my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I have been faced a similar issue. Please try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

In order to toggle airplane mode on Ubuntu, please try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>

It will automatically turnoff aeroplane mode.

Comment: Interesting! How do you square this with the accepted answer that says *"A review of MSI's manual for your notebook PC shows the manufacturer is Windows-centric, for they provided no drivers, Linux utilities, or physical switch to cycle wireless."* ? Has something changed in the past 4 years?